# ROUND T-SQL of values 0.0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a Select statement where I have to show the average of genres but the result must show the 0 values as 0.0

My code is

```
SELECT genreName AS 'Genre'
       , CAST(CASE WHEN
                   AVG(rateValue) IS NULL
                   THEN 0
               ELSE ROUND(FORMAT(AVG(rateValue),2),0.0)
               END AS FLOAT) AS 'Average Rating'
FROM [IMDB].[FilmGenre] flmgnr
     LEFT JOIN [IMDB].[FilmGenreAllocation] flmgnrall
     ON(flmgnrall.genreId = flmgnr.genreId)
     LEFT JOIN [IMDB].[Film] flm
     ON(flm.filmId = flmgnrall.filmId)
     LEFT JOIN [IMDB].[FilmReview] flmrvw
     ON(flmrvw.filmId = flmgnrall.filmId)
GROUP BY genreName;
GO
```

and the result must be

```
+---------+----------------+
|  Genre  | Average Rating |
+---------+----------------+
| Action  | 0.00           |
| Comedy  | 4.67           |
| Crime   | 4.50           |
| Drama   | 4.50           |
| Family  | 0.00           |
| Mystery | 4.40           |
+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Better leave presentation stuff to the presentation layer...

Comment: Yes, it can be, but he have to fix his qry first. With THEN 0 he cast implicitly whole case statement to int. He didn't write it, but probably he got only integer output instead of expected float number.

Comment: You could use `Coalesce( Avg( rateValue ), 0.0 )` to handle the `NULL` rather than a `CASE`.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Zohar Peled.  This should really be in the presentation layer.

However, if you must, one option is to use the Format() function if 2012+, or just cast as decimal

```
...Format(IsNull(AVG(rateValue),0),'#0.00')
```

or

```
...Cast(IsNull(AVG(rateValue),0) as decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast your values to float, but rather to `DECIMAL(18,2)` like so:

```
CAST(CASE WHEN
               AVG(rateValue) IS NULL
               THEN 0
           ELSE ROUND(FORMAT(AVG(rateValue),2),0.0)
           END AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS 'Average Rating'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
THEN 0
```

try

```
THEN 0.0
```

With 0 you told to SQL Server - case is int data type.

Or better way from:

```
 CAST(CASE WHEN
        AVG(rateValue) IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE ROUND(FORMAT(AVG(rateValue),2),0.0)
     END AS FLOAT)
```

Make:

```
1.0 * ROUND(ISNULL(AVG(rateValue), 0), 1) -- isnull assume data type from first item
```